# Java - Program which remembers/saves entered fields

Tags: java, swing, save, jtextfield

I have a program that uses three `JTextField` fields as the main data entry fields. I want to have it so that when the user terminates the program and then opens it again, their last entry will still be in the fields.

How could I achieve this? Would I need some sort of database or is there a simpler way?

Comment: It is just the form of the data that you are asking about?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I just want the data entered into the text fields there when the user restarts the program.

Comment: I was not asking about what you 'want'.  Be specific.  What part are you having a problem with?  Is it 1) Detecting the program close. 2) The form of the data. 3) The way to de/serialize the data. --- There are a dozen forms the data can be stored in, multiple places it can be stored, different ways it might be read/written, tricks to detect program exit.  ***Try to narrow it down as to what you are having trouble with.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest way to achieve this is to add a listener to the text field and use the java preferences api:

```
textField = new JTextField();
    // set document listener
    textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyListener());
    // get the preferences associated with your application
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("unique_string_representing_your_preferences");
    // load previous value
    textField.setText(prefs.get("your_preference_unique_key", ""));

class MyListener implements DocumentListener {

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
        final Document document = event.getDocument();
        // get the preferences associated with your application
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("unique_string_representing_your_preferences");
        try {
            // save textfield value in the preferences object
            prefs.put("your_preference_unique_key", document.getText(0, document.getLength()));
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    }
}
```

but in this way every time you change value in the text field it is saved. If you want to save it only when application is closed, you can add a WindowListener to your application and write in its

> windowClosing

method the content of the previous changedUpdate.

Answer (score 7):

> Would I need some sort of database..

No.  A D/B is overkill for '3 strings'.

> ..or is there a simpler way?

There's more than one.

1. [Object serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).
2. A [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) with 3 lines of text.
3. [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html)/[Decoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html).
4. A [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file.
5. The [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API.
6. An app. deployed using [JWS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can use the [PersistenceService](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).

That's all I can recall off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest looking at the [Java Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html) system, since this can handle saving information per user or for the whole system.

As an example:

```
void writeMethod() {
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(this);
    prefs.put("key", "value");
}

void readMethodInSameClass() {
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(this);
    prefs.get("key");
}
```

[This description](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/preferences/) may be better than the API reference.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options, you might want to save the data to a configuration file and load it at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You could serialize them and store them in a file: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm