# From jar file to create an xml file

Tags: java, xml, swing

I have made a jar file in swing which is basically a input form. In this input form there is "Save" button. My requirement is when I click on to the save button it will automatically generate a .xml file. Does it possible? If it is, please provide me some useful link.

Comment: [Java API for XML Processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) and [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+xml&oq=java+xml&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61l3.1111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: See also [`XMLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) as well as a [plethora of alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10061909/418556).

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it is a question that you can ask on this website, but assuming that it is a valid question:

It is possible, one of the simplest solutions is JAXB. You may read the documentation: https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.7/docs/ or a very simple example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/.

In nutshell: you need an annotated class and then use a JAXB Marshaller to convert an object to XML.

Answer (score -1):

Put all your form values into one single Java class and then use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to serialize it to an XML file. It is very easy to use (easier than JAXB in my opinion).